# Is it worth learning the Vedas in the absence of a Guru?

Tags: vedas

Long ago,children used to go to gurukool to learn scriptures under a Guru.Nowadays,since the options are very limited I was wondering if we can learn the Vedas o our own.

Comment: Vedic studies start itself with the initiation of Savitri by the Guru. So, how can it be possible without the Guru?

Comment: The mentioned post https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8964/13242 does not have any answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking about Swa-Adhyayana or Swadhyaya of vedas without a Guru.

Vedic / Upanishadic knowledge is symbolic and difficult to understand. Especially, the ritual part  described in  Brihadaranyaka and Chandogya Upanishads ( ritual symbolism) . Unless one  know the technical and practical aspects of the rituals and their significance, one will not understand their symbolism or true meaning.

The vedas teach us about the  Brahman - the highest Universal Principle  or the Ultimate Truth  .One  also cannot learn about the Ultimate Truth from the Scriptures through personal reading and self-interpretation — the teaching must come from an Authority.The vedas  have to be learnt /understood  by heart, learning  the correct way of pronouncing the mantras by listening to the   mantras chanted  by the guru (teacher). And the correct  meaning should be grasped only through Guru. 
Originally Vedas are never written down and read. They are supposed to have been passed through oral tradition .  Veda Adhyayana implied hearing from the lips of the teacher and repeating after him.

---

That is why Shree Krishna in  [**Bhagavad Gita 4.34**](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=4&field_nsutra_value=34&etgb=1&setgb=1)  is  telling  us to get the   knowledge from a qualified guru.And such a knowledge is only becomes effective.

> तद्विद्धि प्रणिपातेन परिप्रश्नेन सेवया।
>  उपदेक्ष्यन्ति ते ज्ञानं
>   ज्ञानिनस्तत्त्वदर्शिनः।।4.34।।
>
> tad viddhi praṇipātena paripraśnena sevayā
>  upadekṣyanti te jñānaṁ
>   jñāninas tattva-darśinaḥ
>
> **Just try to learn the truth by approaching a spiritual master**. Inquire from him submissively and render service unto him. The
>   self-realized souls can impart knowledge unto you because they have
>   seen the truth.

English Translation Of Sri Shankaracharya's Sanskrit Commentary By Swami Gambirananda

> The considered view of the Lord is that Knowledge imparted by those
>   who have full enlightenment becomes effective, not any other.

---

Therefore its highly recommended to learn vedas from qualified guru who knows the secrets of Vedas ,only By a qualified person ( Dvija) having completed the   Upanayana  samskara.