# The need for a Guru to understand Vedic texts

Tags: vishnu, karma, moksha, guru

Why does Krishna stress on the need for a Guru to attain spritual consciousness? Why is it we can't learn the vedic texts on our own? Why is not self studying not encouraged? The analogy that was given to me was Getting Moksha is like travelling through a dense forest and a Guru is a guide who can help us cross the forest "easily". But If a person tries doing it by his own he could somehow cross it with much much difficulty.. Still he could cross the forest.

1. What if one doesn't have a guru but wants to attain Moksha, how could he attain Moksha?
2. Is it "impossible" to cross the karma without a guru

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to read and understand Vedas without guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/is-it-possible-to-read-and-understand-vedas-without-guru)

Comment: There are plenty of questions regarding this, please search for existing questions and answers. If you can't find it, then you can ask.

Comment: No my question is evn though Vedas are very much difficult to self learn... Is it impossible to self learn them?

Comment: I have edited this question now....