# What is the best way to start learning the Upanishads for beginners and in what order?

Tags: upanishads

Is there any good and authentic source where English version of the Upanishads are available.

Comment: Related: [What order should I read the Vedas and Upanishads in?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3771/277), [Available sources for the 108 Upanishads?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8947/277)

Comment: @Swami-Hello this post https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3771/13242 does not solve my problem.It just explains the different classifications of vedas and Upanishads.Here is what I've got from your post: **"The top-down approach says first read the vedas and then the upanishads."**  ,whereas I am interested in Upanishads right now.Futhermore,the links given there is not useful to me for the moment. Here,I have got the solution I needed to start with the Upanishads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can only tell about the method that helped me. There could be other ways as well. It is a subjective choice. It might help you or might not.

What I realised in the process, that directly reading Upanishads at the first go was not very helpful. Upanishads are relatively complicated to understand for a newbie. But the best part is the concept of the Upanishads are explained in an organised way be later Vedantins, which is more accessible to newbies. So my roadmap was this -

1. First read the central concept of Upanishads. I read this book. Advaita Vedanta: a philosophical reconstruction by Eliot Deutsch. This book is exceptionally organised and gives a concise introduction to the subject. He was the professor emeritus in the University of Hawaii on Indian Philosophy. Link - 
   [Advaita Vedanta: a philosophical reconstruction](https://www.amazon.in/Advaita-Vedanta-Philosophical-Reconstruction-Traditions/dp/0824802713/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1517125545&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=advita%20vedanta%20a%20philosophical%20reconstruction)
2. Next, I read Upanishads with commentary. Without commentary, it would be impossible to get anything meaningful out of it. One of the best translation and commentary on all principal Upanishads is "The Principal Upanishads by Prof. Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan. He was the Professor of Eastern Religion and Ethics at the University of Oxford. When it comes to the order of the Upanishads, read the shortest one first! Start with Isha Upanishad.   Link - 
   [The Principal Upanishads](https://www.amazon.in/Principal-Upanisads-Prof-S-Radhakrishnan/dp/8172231245/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1517125965&sr=1-1&keywords=the%20principal%20upanishads)
3. Next, I would suggest you read the "The Philosophy of the Upanishads" written by Paul Deussen, Professor of Philosophy. This book is lengthy but explains the concepts in a detailed way. It is one of the classics. You can get the book from this link - 
   [The Philosophy of the Upanishads](https://archive.org/details/philosophyupani00deusgoog)

Comment: Did you need the help of a guru to get started?

Comment: In short, NO. Well, some may not agree with me, but the fact is without the initiation by Guru you can't embark on a spiritual journey it is not the standpoint of Upanishad. It is the standpoint of Tantra. Tantra and Vedas are an entirely different stream of thought, and only Vedas has the authority. In Upanishad, there are instances where the pupil learnt about Brahman without the help of his teacher. I do not deny the importance of Guru. Without Guru you can't progress, I firmly reject this statement. Vedanta points out three methods of self-realisation: Read, Reflect and Apply.

Comment: In short, NO--- The Vedic journey itself starts with the initiation of Savitri or the Gayatri Diksha and one who initiates is called the Vedic Guru.. The only difference with the Tantras in this regard is that in Tantras, Mantras are many, but in Vedas the Mantra is only one (viz-the Gayatri Mantra)..   "Without Guru you can't progress, I firmly reject this statement." Who are you to do so to start with? Actually if u read books by un -initiates, non-practitioners, then you can get not just 1 but a 1000s of such misconception about Hinduism..@Amritendu

Comment: Read the Sukta of the Atharva Veda where it's describing how the student receives the new birth by staying in the house of the Guru for 3 nights and then receiving the Gayatri Diksha.. The same thing is there in Tantras or Agamas too and there it's called "Adhivasa"  ... So, without Guru no knowledge in Hinduism whether Vedic or Tantric.. @Amritendu

Comment: I am not preaching dude.. what you are saying is absolutely wrong.. that's why i commented.. Someone needs to correct you right? .. Hinduism starts and ends with the Guru, whether it's Vedic or Tantric.. How will u expect that people will not counter comment when u say something like "In Vedic Dharma Guru is not needed"? Moreover all the Vedas are handed down to us due to the Guru-Shishya lineage.. @Amritendu

Comment: And for ur kind info-- I already have Gurus and Dikshas from them.. @Amritendu So i don't need Gurus like the ones u've mentioned..also there are bad people in every dept. but that does not stop us using that Dept. altogether..

Answer (score 3):

The Ten Principal Upanishads
was compiled and translated to
English by Shree Purohit
Swami and W.B.Yeats .

download option— http://www.holybooks.com/the-ten-principal-upanishads/

Mukhya Upanishads , also known
as Principal Upanishads

1. Īśā , Yajurveda
2. Kena , Samaveda
3. Kaṭha , Yajurveda
4. Praṣna , Atharvaveda
5. Muṇḍaka , Atharvaveda
6. Māṇḍūkya,Atharvaveda
7. Taittirīya , Yajurveda
8. Aitareya , , Rigveda
9. Chāndogya, Samaveda
10. Bṛhadāraṇyaka ,Yajurveda

these ten are the most important and these three conclude 13 major upnishads.

11. Shvetashvatara Upanishad
12. Kaushitaki Upanishad
13. Maitri Upanishad

Translation by Swami Nikhilananda — http://www.vivekananda.net/PDFBooks/upanishads_nikhilananda.pdf

Although there are online reading — http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/upanishadsindex.asp

Max muller translation online:—http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/